# pyparsing 3.0.0 railroad diagram packages produce vertical arrangement

Tags: python-3.x, svg, pyparsing

While generating some railroad diagrams with `pyparsing 3.0.0a2` I came across some graphical errors. The example below (picture and associated SVG file) was generated with the following code example:

```py
from pyparsing import *
a = Literal('HJ').setName('a')
b = Literal('AB').setName('b')
c = Literal('KL').setName('c')
ALL = (a[4] ^ b[5] + c).setName('ALL')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if '3.0.0' in __version__:
        from pyparsing.diagram import to_railroad, railroad_to_html
        with open('test.html', 'w') as fp:
            rr = to_railroad(ALL)
            fp.write(railroad_to_html(rr))
```

As you can see there are three problems:

- When there are more then 4 elements to be disposed next to each other, the generator is representing them vertically
- The size is wrongly set compared to its content (the first point above doesn't seem to influence the size of the picture)
- This vertical arrangement is overlapping with other diagram objects that are supposed to be positioned below

I don't mind to have some vertical arrangement if the SVG size is correctly calculated.

However, is there a way to disable this "feature" is order to keep an horizontal arrangement for successive elements?

---

---

```html
<svg class="railroad-diagram" height="218" width="516" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="background-color:#f5f2f0"><g transform="translate(.5 .5)"><style>svg.railroad-diagram path,svg.railroad-diagram rect{stroke-width:3;stroke:#000;fill:transparent}svg.railroad-diagram text{font:700 14px monospace;text-anchor:middle}svg.railroad-diagram text.comment{font:italic 12px monospace}svg.railroad-diagram rect{fill:#cfc}svg.railroad-diagram rect.group-box{stroke:gray;stroke-dasharray:10 5;fill:none}</style><path d="M20 45v20m10-20v20M20 55h20M40 55h20M60 55h20M154 55"/><rect class="group-box" height="38" rx="10" ry="10" width="74" x="80" y="36"/><g class="terminal"><path d="M80 55h10M144 55h10"/><rect height="22" rx="10" ry="10" width="54" x="90" y="44"/><text x="117" y="59">&apos;HJ&apos;</text></g><g class="non-terminal"><path d="M97 28"/><text class="comment" x="88.5" y="33">a</text></g><path d="M154 55h10M164 55h10M248 55"/><rect class="group-box" height="38" rx="10" ry="10" width="74" x="174" y="36"/><g class="terminal"><path d="M174 55h10M238 55h10"/><rect height="22" rx="10" ry="10" width="54" x="184" y="44"/><text x="211" y="59">&apos;HJ&apos;</text></g><g class="non-terminal"><path d="M191 28"/><text class="comment" x="182.5" y="33">a</text></g><path d="M248 55h10M258 55h10"/><g><path d="M342 55"/><rect class="group-box" height="38" rx="10" ry="10" width="74" x="268" y="36"/><g class="terminal"><path d="M268 55h10M332 55h10"/><rect height="22" rx="10" ry="10" width="54" x="278" y="44"/><text x="305" y="59">&apos;HJ&apos;</text></g><g class="non-terminal"><path d="M285 28"/><text class="comment" x="276.5" y="33">a</text></g></g><path d="M342 55h10M352 55h10"/><g><path d="M436 55"/><rect class="group-box" height="38" rx="10" ry="10" width="74" x="362" y="36"/><g class="terminal"><path d="M362 55h10M426 55h10"/><rect height="22" rx="10" ry="10" width="54" x="372" y="44"/><text x="399" y="59">&apos;HJ&apos;</text></g><g class="non-terminal"><path d="M379 28"/><text class="comment" x="370.5" y="33">a</text></g></g><path d="M436 55h20M60 55a10 10 0 0110 10v42a10 10 0 0010 10"/><g><path d="M80 117h121M201 117h10M211 117h10M295 117h10"/><rect class="group-box" height="38" rx="10" ry="10" width="74" x="221" y="98"/><g class="terminal"><path d="M221 117h10M285 117h10"/><rect height="22" rx="10" ry="10" width="54" x="231" y="106"/><text x="258" y="121">&apos;AB&apos;</text></g><g class="non-terminal"><path d="M238 90"/><text class="comment" x="229.5" y="95">b</text></g><path d="M305 117a10 10 0 0110 10v7a10 10 0 01-10 10h-94a10 10 0 00-10 10v23a10 10 0 0010 10M211 187h10M295 187h10"/><rect class="group-box" height="38" rx="10" ry="10" width="74" x="221" y="168"/><g class="terminal"><path d="M221 187h10M285 187h10"/><rect height="22" rx="10" ry="10" width="54" x="231" y="176"/><text x="258" y="191">&apos;AB&apos;</text></g><g class="non-terminal"><path d="M238 160"/><text class="comment" x="229.5" y="165">b</text></g><path d="M305 187a10 10 0 0110 10v7a10 10 0 01-10 10h-94a10 10 0 00-10 10v23a10 10 0 0010 10"/><g><path d="M211 257h10M295 257h10"/><rect class="group-box" height="38" rx="10" ry="10" width="74" x="221" y="238"/><g class="terminal"><path d="M221 257h10M285 257h10"/><rect height="22" rx="10" ry="10" width="54" x="231" y="246"/><text x="258" y="261">&apos;AB&apos;</text></g><g class="non-terminal"><path d="M238 230"/><text class="comment" x="229.5" y="235">b</text></g></g><path d="M305 257a10 10 0 0110 10v7a10 10 0 01-10 10h-94a10 10 0 00-10 10v23a10 10 0 0010 10"/><g><path d="M211 327h10M295 327h10"/><rect class="group-box" height="38" rx="10" ry="10" width="74" x="221" y="308"/><g class="terminal"><path d="M221 327h10M285 327h10"/><rect height="22" rx="10" ry="10" width="54" x="231" y="316"/><text x="258" y="331">&apos;AB&apos;</text></g><g class="non-terminal"><path d="M238 300"/><text class="comment" x="229.5" y="305">b</text></g></g><path d="M305 327a10 10 0 0110 10v7a10 10 0 01-10 10h-94a10 10 0 00-10 10v23a10 10 0 0010 10"/><g><path d="M211 397h10M295 397h10"/><rect class="group-box" height="38" rx="10" ry="10" width="74" x="221" y="378"/><g class="terminal"><path d="M221 397h10M285 397h10"/><rect height="22" rx="10" ry="10" width="54" x="231" y="386"/><text x="258" y="401">&apos;AB&apos;</text></g><g class="non-terminal"><path d="M238 370"/><text class="comment" x="229.5" y="375">b</text></g></g><path d="M305 397h10M315 397h121"/></g><path d="M436 397a10 10 0 0010-10V65a10 10 0 0110-10M456 55h20M40 55a10 10 0 0110 10v104a10 10 0 0010 10"/><g><path d="M60 179h161M295 179h161"/><rect class="group-box" height="38" rx="10" ry="10" width="74" x="221" y="160"/><g class="terminal"><path d="M221 179h10M285 179h10"/><rect height="22" rx="10" ry="10" width="54" x="231" y="168"/><text x="258" y="183">&apos;KL&apos;</text></g><g class="non-terminal"><path d="M238 152"/><text class="comment" x="229.5" y="157">c</text></g></g><path d="M456 179a10 10 0 0010-10V65a10 10 0 0110-10M476 55h20m-10-10v20m10-20v20"/></g></svg>
```

[image: Picture with errors]
[image: Picture with a more correct size]

---

---

### Addendum for 3.0.0b1 compared to 3.0.0a2

[image: pyparsing==3.0.0b1]
[image: pyparsing==3.0.0a2]

And a small correction the sequence is supposed to be:
`ALL = (a[4] ^ b[5] ^ c).setName('ALL')` to correspond to the diagrams.

Comment: I just notice there is a `vertical` parameter that can be use for this. So the change is:
```rr = to_railroad(ALL, vertical=False)```. Note the error can still happen if this `vertical` parameter is set low enough (default at 5).

Comment: Glad to see you trying out the pre-release, thanks! I'm pushing out .b1 release this week, with a little more accessible method for diagram creation, including the `vertical` argument so that this is more clearly configurable for the user..

Comment: 3.0.0b1 was released yesterday, please see the changes in testing for pyparsing version using `pyparsing.__version_info__` and in creating diagrams using `ParserElement.create_diagram`.

Comment: I just tried this last version to create a railroad diagrams and the result is strange. Indeed the previous version was naturally placing the ORed elements vertically and the ANDed element horizontally with some limitations due to the `vertical` parameter. But now all the ORed elements are placed horizontally without any options possible.

Comment: I used this command using the latest version: `ALL.create_diagram("vert.html", vertical=6)` and all elements are horizontal. Change vertical to 3, 4, or 5 to see differences in the layout.

Thanks again for testing out these pre-release versions, btw!

Comment: Exactly, everything is now horizontal whereas before the AB line was below the HJ line. I am adding the picture obtained in the question body.